# Change default Automatic Package Updater Chocolatey output path to avoid output will be pushed to GitHub

Tags: git, github, automation, chocolatey, nuspec

**Introduction**

**Aim:** define output directory for automatically created Chocolatey packages by ketarin to avoid that automatically created nuspec packages will be pushed to GitHub

The steps located in [this manual](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/AutomaticPackages) have been followed to create a Chocolatey Packages automatically. One of the steps is to specify the path to the directory where the Automatic Chocolatey Package templates reside. These Packages are maintained in a GitHub repository which have been cloned on the computer.

*chocopkgup.exe.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PackagesFolder" value="C:\path\to\chocolateyautomatic"/>
    <add key="TokenReplaceFileSearchPattern" value="*.txt|*.nuspec|*.ps1|*.config"/>
    <add key="PS1FileToExecute" value="ChocoPkgUp.ps1"/>
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

A Windows Scheduled task to run ketarin.exe every hour has been created. According the log the nuspec package is created in the directory `C:\path\to\chocolateyautomatic\output` which is defined as `PackagesFolder` in the `chocopkgup.exe.config` file.

*chocolatey.package.updater.log*

```
2014-06-14 19:05:01,884 [INFO ] - Attempting to build package from 'packagename.nuspec'.
Successfully created package 'C:\path\to\chocolateyautomatic\_output\packagename\packageversion\packagename.packageversion.nupkg'.
```

To avoid that the Automatically created Chocolatey packages will be seen as changes to be committed if `git status` will be executed, another `output` path for automatically created Chocolatey Packages would like to be defined in the `chocopkgup.exe.config`

**Question**

How to change output directory of automatically created Chocolatey Packages by ketarin to avoid that the created nuspec packages are created in GitHub checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not a direct answer to your question, can you not simply change the .gitignore file to exclude those files and folders?

This is what I have done here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-coreteampackages/blob/master/.gitignore

Hope that helps!

Gary

Comment: Boo. You want the output in that particular repository.

Comment: @ferventcoder I have checked your [chocolateyautomaticpackage](https://github.com/ferventcoder/chocolateyautomaticpackages/tree/master/_output) repository and the _output directory has been committed to GitHub. I thought the _output directory should be omitted, but I will commit it now.

Comment: I find it useful for when folks want to post fixes.